# Differences Between Multiples of Consecutive Odd Primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For each pair of consecutive odd prime numbers, regardless of the difference between them, there will be points on the whole number line where the two odd primes are factors of a pair of numbers that differ by 2. For example, 7 and 11 differ by 4. 11 is a factor of 33. 7 is a factor of 35. 33 and 35 differ by 2. 7 is a factor of 42. 11 is a factor of 44. 42 and 44 differ by 2. Notice that in between 33 and 35 is 34, in between 42 and 44 is 43, and that 34 and 43 sum to 77, the product of 7 and 11.

What branch of mathematics is this? Has this been studied before? What words is this called by? Do you know of another way to describe this? Does this seem significant?

It seems to be very elementary and time consuming. I understand that it holds true for every pair of consecutive odd primes. There will always be the products of the two primes, where the difference is 0 (77, the multiple of 7, minus 77, the multiple of 11, equals 0). We can put the two primes in arithmetic progressions and compare the terms. 7 and 11 differ by 4. 14 and 22 differ by 8. 21 and 33 differ by 12. Notice that at this point, the difference of 12 is 1 more than 11, and it is here that we have 33 and 35. 28 and 44 differ by 16. The difference increases by 4 each time. 35 and 55 differ by 20. 42 and 66 differ by 24. 49 and 77 differ by 28, a multiple of 7. At this point, 77-77=0. There are definite patterns. How are they best described?

The number that is exactly centered in between 7 and 11 is 9. 9-2=7. 9+2=11. Notice that 43-34=9.

I have written several pages of such patterns on paper. Of what importance, if any, do you think these patterns are?

Comment: Let our two primes be $p$ and $q$. Since $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime, there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $px-qy=1$. It follows that $(2x)p-(2y)q=2$.

Comment: It follows from Bézout's identity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity

Comment: Indeed, you can find multiples of those two primes that differ by 1. or any fixed number you choose in advance. and the primes don't need to be consecutive. indeed, they don't even have to be prime - any two numbers whose greatest common divisor equals 1 will do.